# secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchos-2

In two applications which have `WatchKit` app extensions, I receive the following `error` in the device log more than ten times on startup.

```
secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
```

Folks over at the `Apple Developer forums` have also reported this.  Thread here...

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20193

But, no one has found any solution.

Anyone have any ideas?

The app does start and run fine, but I'm concerned that these messages / errors might be slowing launch and / or indicating I con't have the project configured correctly.

Comment: Anything new to this topic?

Comment: I'm seeing same errors with Today App Extension. It seems to be working, but can't access shared user defaults. However, it's working just fine with non-production build.