# Keychain: secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements:

Tags: ios, keychain

When I launch my app, I can see several logs with the same message:
secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found

I use keychain to store passwords, but why I'm getting those messages?

Comment: you can also see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35556050/sectaskdiagnoseentitlements-missing-keychain-entitlements-no-stored-taskref-fou

Comment: nice, but without any answer either